# How to show search results?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am working on an e-commerce website. While searching for a product, the results are shown on the results page after checking with the database. Is there any software/code/library available to get the following things done:

1. Search results split over several pages with page numbers (1, 2...)
2. Search results having filter criteria like brand name, price range
   etc.
3. When user selects for different filer criteria (like *price range* or
   *brand name* or *sort by price*), the page should not refresh and update
   the results there itself.
4. Any other relevant functionality (like *"sort by price"* feature, *"list or grid view"* feature)

Comment: Look at jQuery and http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DynamicList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at jQuery and http://www.datatables.net

Comment: I've resorted to datatables for a project I'm working on. How does it handle large amount of data?

Comment: I've got jQuery running with millions of records.  The trick is using Ajax to get paged results and "pipelining" the result set to speed changing between pages.  There are simple, easy to use instructions on datatables.net to help you with both.

Answer (score -2):

1. [Paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)
2. Display a list of filter options, filter results accordingly.
3. [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)
4. [Sortable grid](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Sortable%20grid)